# Is it possible to use wild cards in angularjs mocks

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use wild cards in angular mocks? for example:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/checklists/*').respond({ userId: 'userX' }, { 'A-Token': 'xxx' });
```

rather than:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/checklists/123').respond({ userId: 'userX' }, { 'A-Token': 'xxx' });
```

Comment: You meaning something like `'/api/checklists/:id'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend) suggests that it takes in a regular expression, so you can do something like this:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', /\/api\/checklists\/[1-9][0-9]*/)
```

This will require the match an integer ID with a length of at least 1, not starting with zero.  Of course, this is just an example.  Create your own regular expressions to match.

Comment: Took me a while to get my head round the javascript regular expression syntax. Thanks

Comment: Note that while regexes are supported, one `$httpBackend` expectation will still match only one request, and moreover, order or expectations is important. So if you have N requests happening, you have to still do (exactly) N `$httpBackend.when` calls. This limits the usefulness of the wildcards a lot.